# Running python unit-test on cloud build with datastore emulator not working when submitting build

Tags: google-cloud-build

For my CI/CD pipeline, I want to launch my python unit-test on cloud build (with a github trigger). To run my test I need a datastore emulator to create entity in a safe env (to isolate my tests builds after builds).
My python app is a classic Flask app running on python 3.7 for app engine standard env.

I tried to submit my build (`gcloud beta builds submit --config build.yaml .`) but the build stuck at the last steps and output nothing (only one log: `Step #2: Already have image (with digest): gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker`).

On local env, I have run the emulator inside a docker container, then ran my test container and it is working.
Moreover, when running with cloud-build-local, the tests are working and my build finish with status DONE.

Here is my cloud build YAML:

```
steps:
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  entrypoint: /bin/sh
  args:
  - '-c'
  - |
    docker run -d -p 9225:9225 google/cloud-sdk gcloud beta emulators datastore start --project=test --consistency=1 --host-port 0.0.0.0:9225
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  args: ['build', '--rm', '-f', './Dockerfile', '-t', 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/core-test:latest', '.']
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  args: ['run', 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/core-test:latest']
```

Here is the Dockerfile:

```
FROM gcr.io/google-appengine/python

RUN apt-get update

RUN virtualenv /venv -p python3.7

ENV VIRTUAL_ENV /venv
ENV PATH /venv/bin:$PATH

# Copy the application's source code
WORKDIR /app

ADD . /app

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt -r requirements-dev.txt

RUN mkdir ../data

ENV DATASTORE_PROJECT_ID=test
ENV DATASTORE_EMULATOR_HOST=host.docker.internal:9225
ENV PYTHON_ENV=TestConfig

CMD nosetests
```

The tests call my API endpoints that are creating entity in the datastore emulator.

I would like to see my test running and my build to succeed but I don't understand what I am doing wrong.
Is it the proper use of cloud build for CI purposes? Is cloud build able to run a docker container inside a build?
The only documentation on testing with cloud build is [here](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/configuring-builds/build-test-deploy-artifacts#running_unit_tests_and_integration_tests) but I can not find more information.

Comment: Hi, I'm running into the same issue. Were you able to figure out what was wrong?

Comment: I'm still working on my issue where GCP runs oddly differently and I have no solution for yours and I know it has been a year but anybody stumbling on this odd issue should be aware of tunshell.com to remote into GCP.